# Trigger a button click on a moon.Button or moon.IconButton with jQuery/Javascript directly

Tags: javascript, jquery, enyo

I know  the click action can be triggered by assigning ontap a specific function like so:

```
{
kind: "moon.Button",name :"search_button",  
content : "Search" , ontap : "searchAction", classes: "menu-button-style"
}
```

.
.
.

```
searchAction : function(){  //do some stuff on click}
```

I've tried

```
$('#id_of_my_button').click();
$('#id_of_my_button').trigger('click');
```

and none of those seem to work.

simplified [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fabii23/2AWb5/3/)

Any ideas

Comment: it will be better if you post a jsfiddle.

Comment: @celerno added fiddle.

Comment: You could try using a `setTimeout` with a slight delay to fire your jquery code, allowing the other script time to finish rendering the button

Comment: @celerno, sorry I might not have been clear enough, the issue isn't that button is not rendered in time. I just wnat to be able to use jQuery or JS to trigger a clikc action on the button. Possibly from another function or listener later on down the line. After the button renders if I try triggering a click method through the chrome console nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Djspaceg/2AWb5/6/

Enyo has a global handle (`enyo`) you can use if you need to access any part of its structure. It's not recommended for use from within our app, since it breaks encapsulation, but since you're already outside enyo (by using jQuery or plain JavaScript) I don't see as much harm.

```
function TapThat() {
    // 'enyo' is the global namespace.
    // The '$' refers to the children of the object/kind.
    enyo.$.tappyButton.tapAction();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why trigger the click with jquery?  You can force an event with Enyo, as well:

this.$.someButton.bubble("ontap", {...});

Answer (score 1):

Using the native [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click) function of elements seems to work in your case, like this:

```
window.onload = function (){
    document.getElementById('tappyButton').click();
};
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2AWb5/4/)

Your problem in the fiddle is that you haven't included jQuery. Also, probably that you don't wait for the element to be added to the DOM before binding a click listener to it.

[Demo with jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/2AWb5/5/)